# Почему процедура в MySQL всегда возвращает OK

Tags: mysql

Доброе время суток, я своял процедуру, которая должна получить самую старую запись и обновить дату обращения к этой записи, при вызове

> mysql> CALL User();
>
> Query OK, 1 row affected (0,06 sec)

Всегда будет возвращатся ОК 
Я так понимаю это потому что возвращается результат работы функции UPDATE 
Если убрать запрос UPDATE то возвращается нормальный результат select как и должно быть...

Собственно вопрос как оставить UPDATE но что бы процедура возвращала результат работы select?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`h`@`%` PROCEDURE `User`()
BEGIN
SELECT
    userP.id,
    userP.username,
INTO
    @id,
    @username,
FROM
    `User`
ORDER BY
    DateUse ASC limit 1;
UPDATE `User` SET DateUse=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id=@id;
END
```

Comment: Что делает ваш селект и зачем его надо возвращать?

Comment: Эм... делает выборку из БД, мне просто при выборке надо обновить дату последнего обращения к записи... Вот я и хочу делать это процидурой

Comment: Query OK возвращает НЕ процедура, а сам запрос. Весь вывод в процедуре безусловно идёт в выходной поток. *как оставить UPDATE но что бы процедура возвращала результат работы select?* Два запроса - два вывода. Два набора данных, если вызов не с консоли. Соответственно в программе берёшь нужный тебе - тупо по порядковому номеру.

Comment: Я кажется понял о чем вы - но вот что странно, я в php всегда получаю false при выводи - может у вас есть хороший пример на php как это можно сделать?